# Can I choose active/hover item with dialog (shell script)?

Tags: shell, menu, dialog

I'm using the [dialog](http://invisible-island.net/dialog/manpage/dialog.html) library. My command is:

```
  dialog --stdout \
    --menu 'Menu' \
    0 0 0 \
    1 'Option A' \
    2 'Option B' \
    9 'Exit'
```

I'd like that "Option B" is active/hover when the menu appears. Like this image:

[image]

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used this program, but in the documentation you linked to I see the following:

```
--default-item string
    Set the default item in a checklist, form or menu box. Normally the first
    item in the box is the default.
```

Have you tried this?

Comment: Helped me a lot. Thanks! I hadn't seen.